# Discord bot that replys to a direct message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using discord.js and I'm trying to make if a user sends a direct message to a bot, it will respond a simple reply such as "I'm sorry, You can not DM me. Please use the ticket system instead."

I tried using:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
    msg.author.send(" blah blah example text");
    return;
  }
});
```

This yields no results.

I'm totally new to coding and I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know if the first `if` goes through? Could you put a console.log inside to see? This could be a first step towards figuring out what's not working.

Also make sure that your Discord settings are correct and that you can receive DMs.

Comment: I see that it doesnt go through. Any ideas to solve this? Nothing is printing on the console log

Comment: Maybe try to `console.log(msg.channel.type)` before the if and see what value you should be checking for in DMs

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Im using the latest one. I think its v13?

Comment: I used console log - when interacting with the bot on DM - nothing happens. Seems the bot cant recieve DM? Although it is set as admin?

Comment: Can the bot receive message events if it's not in a dm, like can it see a message in a guild?

Comment: It sees a guild text. I set for him a few commands and everything works. The console logs them as well.

Comment: @Avtester maybe look at this issue: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/5516#issuecomment-985458524 

Seems similar.

Comment: @antonie ok I got some progress. Using these intents and partials, the console log now shows that the bot recieve dms. But it still cant send messages

Answer (score 4):

OK, now I solved this for good.

I was missing:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS", "DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING"], partials: ['CHANNEL',] })
```

(used this guide: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/5516#issuecomment-985458524)

For the reply:

```
  if (message.channel.type === "DM") {
     return message.reply({ content: "TEXT" });
   }
```

I should've used CAPITAL **DM**, Jesus Christ.
Now it works like a charm.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score -1):

Your using the message event, so it needs a command to function.

`if (message.content === "test")`, your command is in the String.

`if (message.channel.type === "dm")`, and this detects what channel type is the user  in for using the command.

`return message.reply("")`, then it will send an error message in the user's dm because the command cannot be executed in dm's.

`else`, if it doesn't detect a dm channel then it will ignore the error response.

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content === "test") {
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
      return message.reply({ content: "This message is a dm for the user." });
    } else {
      return message.reply({ content: "This message is a message sent to channel." });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, If i want the dm to be triggered without a command? what are my options? just an auto reply to any message

Comment: @Avtester, Maybe you can try `message.content === args.join(" ")`. Replace it with the command.

Comment: @Avtester, What do you mean by "return"? Does it not like execute?

Comment: I replaced it with the message content == test, the console said "args is not defined"

Comment: @Avtester, Oh wait I forgot you need to define the arguments, add this on top of the message event: `const prefix = "!";`, then add this inside the message event:

`if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();`

Make sure that the command is below the defining of the arguments.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work either.
I think my problem is that i want the bot to reply on user messaging him on dm, and not by command.